# Two object cover

Tags: php, javascript, object

I'm have an bCoord array which is contains the image x, y position,  width and height. I want to insert other object to the array which is not cover each others. The source bellow working very well if the array objects size is bigger or equal with object that I want to insert there, otherwise not. I have a solution for that, but that is not very nice. If anybody has a nice solution regarding this problem, please share me.

```
this.isCover    =   function(pixel, width, height)
{
    for (var i=0; i<bCoords.length; i++) 
        if (isThereBuilding(bCoords[i],pixel.x, pixel.y) || isThereBuilding(bCoords[i],pixel.x+width, pixel.y) || 
            isThereBuilding(bCoords[i],pixel.x, pixel.y+height) ||isThereBuilding(bCoords[i],pixel.x+width, pixel.y+height) )
                return bCoords[i];               
    return null;
}
function isThereBuilding(obj,x, y) 
{
    return (obj.x <= x && (obj.w+obj.x)>= x) && (obj.y <= y && (obj.h+obj.y) >= y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to check if an objects overlaps another:

```
hitTest = function(o, l){
    function getOffset(o){
        for(var r = {l: o.offsetLeft, t: o.offsetTop, r: o.offsetWidth, b: o.offsetHeight};
            o = o.offsetParent; r.l += o.offsetLeft, r.t += o.offsetTop);
        return r.r += r.l, r.b += r.t, r;
    }
    for(var b, s, r = [], a = getOffset(o), j = isNaN(l.length), i = (j ? l = [l] : l).length; i;
        b = getOffset(l[--i]), (a.l == b.l || (a.l > b.l ? a.l <= b.r : b.l <= a.r))
        && (a.t == b.t || (a.t > b.t ? a.t <= b.b : b.t <= a.b)) && (r[r.length] = l[i]));
    return j ? !!r.length : r;
};
```

Found [here](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=549).